# Net Core 2.0 Mysql database to consume from WebAPI(newbie)

Tags: c#, mysql

So I tried following this guide to link a MySQL database to my web application. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/

Problem is I get these errors when debugging:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Option not supported.
Parameter name: port3306;database

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBaseConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(string key)

WebApplication2.Models.CountryContext.GetConnection() in CountryContext.cs

             21.  return new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

WebApplication2.Models.CountryContext.GetAllCountries() in CountryContext.cs

          29.  using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())

WebApplication2.Controllers.CountriesController.Index() in CountriesController.cs

             16.  return View(context.GetAllCountries());
```

Also I can't figure out after approx 8h of searching how I can make this basic database work and consume data from a website.

I feel like i'm missing something very dumb...

And here's the git for the full application.
https://github.com/uzishan/TestWebAPI

Comment: First, is that your real user and password you pushed to Github? Second, you need an `=` between `port` and `3306`: `...;port=3306;...` . Consider  using `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to avoid syntax errors. Lastly, that is the default port anyway so you can omit it in this case.

Comment: Some notes after reading your code: You're using the service locator (anti-)pattern (e.g. CountriesController), you may want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . You're writing "low level" database access methods, you're aware of Entity Framework or Dapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is [in your connection string](https://github.com/uzishan/TestWebAPI/blob/c2ec2e495f90a251b8c5686c4d0d7f531ed3eba3/WebApplication2/WebApplication2/appsettings.json#L10). It reads:

```
server=localhost;port3306;database=CountryDatabase;user=uzishan;password=mario1234
```

The second component should be:

```
port=3306;
```

Or you can drop that entirely, since it's the MySQL default.